# Installing matplotlib 1.1.0 on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: python

I installed matplotlib 1.1 from source, but I cant get any plot to show.
`python setup.py build` shows the following:

```
BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: 1.1.0
                python: 2.7.2+ (default, Oct  4 2011, 20:06:09)  [GCC 4.6.1]
              platform: linux2

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES
                 numpy: 1.5.1
             freetype2: 12.2.6

OPTIONAL BACKEND DEPENDENCIES
                libpng: 1.2.46
               Tkinter: no
                        * Using default library and include directories for
                        * Tcl and Tk because a Tk window failed to open.
                        * You may need to define DISPLAY for Tk to work so
                        * that setup can determine where your libraries are
                        * located. Tkinter present, but header files are not
                        * found. You may need to install development
                        * packages.

(setup.py:14683): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(setup.py:14683): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(setup.py:14683): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(setup.py:14683): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
            pkg-config: looking for pygtk-2.0 gtk+-2.0
                        * Package pygtk-2.0 was not found in the pkg-config
                        * search path. Perhaps you should add the directory
                        * containing `pygtk-2.0.pc' to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH
                        * environment variable No package 'pygtk-2.0' found
                        * You may need to install 'dev' package(s) to
                        * provide header files.
                  Gtk+: no
                        * Could not find Gtk+ headers in any of
                        * '/usr/local/include', '/usr/include', '.'
       Mac OS X native: no
                    Qt: no
                   Qt4: no
                 Cairo: 1.8.8

OPTIONAL DATE/TIMEZONE DEPENDENCIES
              datetime: present, version unknown
              dateutil: 1.4.1
                  pytz: 2011c

OPTIONAL USETEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: 9.04
                 latex: no
               pdftops: 0.16.7
```

But I think I already have tkinter and gtk libraries. Any help ?

Comment: You mean asking it there?

Comment: Yep :) It's part of the stackexchange-network, so you can simply login with your SO-credentials there. The guys there love questions about Ubuntu :)

Comment: @Quasdunk, I've flagged it and asked it to be moved. If that doesn't work, I'll post it there too. thanx

Comment: I'm sure you'll get help there quickly :) Goo luck!

Comment: The output shows you have no dependecies required for plotting, no tk, no gtk. To get this on Ubuntu do: aptitude build-dep python-matplotlib (You should remove the old installation, and recompile again, see a convinient way here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4781434/installing-latest-matplotlib-version-with-pipy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Oz123's comment, `apt-get build-dep foo` (or aptitude) allows you to pull all packages needed to build *foo* from the repositories. Thus, to install the necessary build dependencies for matplotlib, run `apt-get build-dep matplotlib`